# Этимология слова "сомелье"

Tags: этимология, грамотная-речь

Как произошло это слово? *Банный сомелье* -- это нонсенс?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Этимология слова** [Сомелье. Описание и услуги. | Винный класс](http://www.wineclass.citylady.ru/sommelier.htm)

**Слово «сомелье» (фр. sommelier) происходит от старо-прованского saumalier, означавшего «погонщик вьючного животного».**  Именно с человека, ответственного за перевозку имущества знатных господ, начиналась эта профессия. Или, правильнее сказать, история этого термина.

Позже, когда сомелье стали следить за хозяйством не только в пути, но и заведовать им в имениях. Какое-то время сомелье оставался своего рода «завхозом», постепенно обретая специализацию: кухня и винные погреба. Во Франции 17го века уже есть упоминания сомелье как «служителя стола», работающего под началом метрдотеля. Однако вино ещё не является его главной обязанностью.

А вот в герцогстве Савойском (в котором, кстати, говорили по-французски) – в те времена уже была введена конкретная должность Somigliere.  **В его обязанности входил подбор и подача вин к столу герцога . Во многих источниках именно этот итальянский Somigliere 17го века упоминается как первый сомелье в его современном понимании.**

К 19 веку профессия (должность) сомелье сформировалась и утвердилась как самостоятельная и имеющая схожее значение в разных странах Европы. Сегодня сомелье — это специалист, который отвечает за алкоголь в ресторане (баре).

**2) Чайный сомелье**  [Кто такой "чайный сомелье"?](http://watermarket.ru/articles/548)

Есть ли что-либо общее между вином и чаем? Оба напитка отличаются сложным богатым букетом, обладающим множеством вариаций и требующим особого климата и условий для достижения оптимального вкуса. Подобно винным сомелье, **существуют сомелье чайные, которые могут высказать экспертное мнение по любым аспектам чайного вкуса** и ежедневно пробуют различные чаи, оценивая качество и консистенцию вкуса.

3) **Банного сомелье можно считать специалистом по напиткам в бане**    [Совместим ли алкоголь и сауна | msksauna.ru](http://www.msksauna.ru/vedomosti/info10.html)

Принимать жидкость в процессе посещения бани нужно обязательно. Это необходимо по той причине, что банная процедура воздействует обычно на весь организм в целом, причем подобно достаточно сильным физическим нагрузкам, также много воды теряется через обильное потоотделение. **Очень полезно пить в сауне минеральную воду, прохладный травяной чай, а также русский квас.**